# Mapreduce job spitting java.io.IOException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, jdbc, mapreduce

hadoop - 2.7.3

I am creating a mapreduce job that reads data from HDFS input file and writes data to mysql.

It is throwing an error while initiating connection. There is no additional information like connection refused or classNotFound exception.Simple IO exception and it is not making any sense to me.

```
Error: java.io.IOException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(DBOutputFormat.java:185)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.<init>(ReduceTask.java:540)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:614)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

My mapreduce code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    DBConfiguration.configureDB(conf, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",              
             "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db",
             "user",  
             "password");

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "test");
     job.setJar(DBMapReduce.class);
    job.setMapperClass(DbMapper.class);
     job.setReducerClass(DbSQLReducer.class);       

     job.setMapOutputKeyClass(DBKeyWritable.class);
     job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

     job.setOutputKeyClass(DBOutputWritable.class);
     job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
     job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
     job.setOutputFormatClass(DBOutputFormat.class);
     FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
     DBOutputFormat.setOutput(
             job,
             "table_name",    // output table name
             new String[] { "dummy",
                     "code",
                     "code_type"
    }   //table columns
    );

     System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

    }
```

I have mysql-connector added to classpath,HADOOP_CLASSPATH, -libjars, referenced libraries and lib folder. None of these seem to work.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We were hitting similar problems months ago. We had to connect with the java remote debugger in order to see the detail in the Exception that allowed us to determine the issue. We still have not found out a way to get these necessary details out of the system.

Comment: I got it resolved by adding mysql-connect jar to hadoop libs such as lib under mapreduce folder, hdfs folder, common folder, yarn folder, tools folder. I am sure hadoop is looking for external jars at one of these folders.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a permissions issue when looking at this particular stack trace:

**at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)**

I guess there isn't sufficient write access for the yarn users to the temp directory.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it resolved by adding mysql-connect jar to hadoop libs such as lib under mapreduce folder, hdfs folder, common folder, yarn folder, tools folder. I am sure hadoop is looking for external jars at one of these folders.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this url help out to track the issue :

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/ioexception/java-io-ioexception-how-to-solve-ioexception/

Track the issue by using try and catch then might be possible to fix.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it resolved by adding mysql-connect jar to hadoop libs such as lib under mapreduce folder, hdfs folder, common folder, yarn folder, tools folder. I am sure hadoop is looking for external jars at one of these folders.